# left join and count doesn't work properly in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, left-join

I have two tables named `A` and `B`, here you can See `A` and `B`

```
A    |  id   |   title
-------------------------
         1   |    A1
         2   |    A2
         3   |    A3   

B    |  A_id   |   title
-------------------------
         1     |    B1
         1     |    B2
         1     |    B3
```

what i want to do is to count The number of `A_id`'s in B, i've tried the following query :

```
select A.title as "title",count(title) as "count" from A left join B on A.id = B.A_id
```

This will give me the following result :

```
title  |  count
---------------
  A1   |    3
  A2   |    1
  A3   |    1
  A4   |    1
```

what i need to have is :

```
title  |  count
---------------
  A1   |    3
  A2   |    0
  A3   |    0
  A4   |    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issues with your query:

1. You query is missing a `GROUP BY` clause. You seem to be using a version of MySQL where option `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled, so, instead of throwing a proper error at you, MySQL happily executes your query.
2. `count(title)` is ambiguous, since the column exists in both tables. This should generate an error. You actually want to count on a column that is coming from table `B`; I would use `B.A_id`, just in case some records in `B` have an null `title`.

Consider:

```
select A.title, count(B.A_id) as `count`
from A 
left join B on A.id = B.A_id
group by A.title
```

Side notes:

- in MySQL, I would suggest using backticks for identifiers rather than double quotes; that's the MySQL way does it
- `A.title as title` is redondant: it is equivalent to just `A.title`

Answer (score 2):

try like below by adding `B.A_id` inside count

```
 select A.title as "title",count(B.A_id) as "count" 
from A left join B on A.id = B.A_id
group by A.title
```